# Fixed width font in LATEX .Rnw file

Tags: fonts

In a .Rmd file, I can force individual words to become fixed width font by using `syntax`.

For example, in the above sentence, the word "syntax" will be written in fixed width format.

Is there an equivalent syntax to force single words in a .Rnw file to become fixed width font?

Thank you.

Comment: Try: `\texttt{syntax}`

Comment: Thank you, it worked! And what it if it is several lines that I want in fixed width format?

Comment: If you want to set blocks of code, you could use the [`listings` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings).